# Given a set of complex subspaces, find a set of disjoint subspaces such that every original subspace is the span of the union of some subset

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Suppose $S$ is a set of subspaces of $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ for some integer $n$.

I would like to find a set $T$ of *disjoint* subspaces (not just pairwise disjoint - is there a clearer word for this?), such that for all $V \in S$, there exists a subset $T_{V}$ of $T$ such that $\text{span}(\bigcup\limits_{X \in T_{V}} X) = V$.

I'm interested in actually doing this in practice, so I'm looking for something reasonably efficient - in particular, I'd like to avoid examining every combination (of any size) of the subspaces!

Comment: Two subspaces cannot be disjoint. Regarding "not just pairwise disjoint": Pairwise disjointness is a _stronger_ condition than disjointness...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Regarding disjointness: Typically you'd say subspaces are disjoint iff their intersection is the zero space. +1 for the other remark :)

Comment: @John What representation of the members of $S$ do you have? Do you have a basis? An orthonormal basis? A deciding function?...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich By disjoint I mean that the sum of the rank of the subspaces is equal to the rank of the span of the union of the subspaces.

Comment: @AlexR I have an explicit basis for each member.

Comment: "rank" applies to transformations. "dimension" applies to subspaces.

Comment: @JohnHughes Apologies - I'm new to this terminology, as must be clear!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich (or others): For future reference, is there an established term for my intended meaning of disjoint?

Comment: Possibly you should just say what you mean. As we see - AlexR said that disjointness meant the intersection was zero, but it turns out what you meant was something different. (Since in your terminology "disjoint" is actually _stronger_ than "pairwise disjoint", the word "disjoint" is in any case a very bad choice.)

Comment: You mean LINEAR subspaces. What if T is the set of all 1-dimensional linear subspaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem in your formulation. We can look at $\mathbb R^2$ instead of any complex vector space to illustrate.

Let $S = \{\langle e_1 \rangle, \langle e_2 \rangle, \langle e_1 + e_2 \rangle\}$. (Thus $S$ contains the $x$-Axis, the $y$-Axis and the $x=y$ line).
What would you chose $T$ to be? For any reasonable interpretation of the problem, you'd have to chose $T=S$, but $S$ isn't "disjoint" since it contains three subspaces of dimension $1$ and the superspace only has dimension $2$.

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you for the clear counterexample to my assumption that this was possible!